# Can we use addView() to populate the container which is already populated with other View

Tags: android, view, android-fragments

I am using following code to load the graph generated by agraph class into the R.id.TranFrag container. but it doesn't show anything when executed. please help

```
Agraph agraph = new Agraph(getActivity(),30);
LinearLayout mainContainer = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.TranFrag);
mainContainer.addView(agraph);
```

where Agraph.java is as below

```
package com.salgaonkar.roomies_v3;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class Agraph extends View {
private Paint paint;
private float MaxY = 20; 
float horstart = 0;
public Agraph(Context context , float MaxY) {
    super(context);     
    paint = new Paint();
    this.MaxY = MaxY;
    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float Height = getHeight()-20;
    float Width = getWidth();
    canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
    for (int i=0; i<=10; i++) {     
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        paint.setTextSize(20.0f);
        float y = ((Height / 10) * i)+20;
        Log.d("y: ",""+y);
        Log.d("lable", ""+(MaxY)*(10-i)/10);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf((MaxY)*(10-i)/10),0,y,paint);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I create a sample project, now I am calling fragment activity and pass main activity context as parameter and in fragment I create a constructor call Agraph and add view.
In activity

```
Fragment f = new TestFragment(this);
```

and in fragment

```
public TestFragment(FExampleActivity fExampleActivity) {
    Agraph agraph = new Agraph(fExampleActivity,30);
    LinearLayout mainContainer = (LinearLayout)fExampleActivity.findViewById(R.id.frags);
    mainContainer.addView(agraph);
}
```

THIS WORK FOR ME..,.

Comment: i have already populated the container with the ListView and onclick event i want to replace that ListView  with the graph i think view is getting added in container but somehow it is not visible .

Answer (score 0):

Seems view Agraph doesn't implements onMeasure(int, int) method.
Try to add something like:

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

setMeasuredDimension(100, 100);

}
```

Comment: if your LinearLayout (matches screen width) contains other view and orientation is horizontal new added view would be out of screen, check this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Agraph agraph = new Agraph(getActivity(),30);
            LinearLayout mainContainer = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.TranFrag);
            mainContainer.addView(agraph);
```

ok now i found the error in above code actual it adds view in container but it was not visible due to container was already

populated with the ListView so i change code like this

```
Agraph agraph = new Agraph(getActivity(),30);
            LinearLayout mainContainer = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.TranFrag); 
            mainContainer.removeAllViews(); //added
            mainContainer.addView(agraph);
```

now it works fine.

Comment: try to add one more view in linear, do you see it? ;)